# Set Sampler states: Linear, Bilinear, Trilinear Filtering/Interpolation

Tags: c++, directx, c

How do you set each of these sampler states in the hlsl

1. Linear filtering
2. Bilinear filtering
3. Trilinear filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter mode is not set in HLSL.  It is part of the `ID3D11SamplerState` object, specified as part of the [D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct during creation.

For example:

```
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC desc;
desc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_LINEAR_MIP_POINT; // bilinear
desc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR; // trilinear
desc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC; // anisotropic
// no such thing as "linear" for 2D textures
// ...
device->CreateSamplerState(&desc, &sampler);
context->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &sampler);
```

And in HLSL:

```
Texture2D foo : register(t0);
SamplerState bar : register(s0);
// ...
foo.Sample(bar, coord);
```

Comment: what is the register information in the HLSL?

Comment: [Register syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607359(v=vs.85).aspx) defines what bind points to use when hooking up objects to the rendering pipeline.  For example, the 0 in PSSetSamplers corresponds to register s0.  The code would do the same thing if you used 7 and "s7".  Note that it is valid to exclude the register syntax, but the compiler will still assign the object to the lowest free slot by default.